# Error in Simple chat application using RMI in java

Tags: java, rmi

I am creating a simplechat app with RMI, But I am not able recognize that where the exact problem is?
This is my code:

**ChatServer.java**

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author nick
 */
public class ChatServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IChat{

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ChatServer() throws RemoteException{
        try {
            Naming.bind("//localhost:1099/chat", this);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

        System.out.println("Chat Server Ready");
    }




    public void put(Point p) throws RemoteException{

        p.getX();
        p.getY();

    }
 /*
    public ArrayList<String> get() throws RemoteException{

        return list;

    } */
    public ArrayList<String> get() throws RemoteException
    {
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new ChatServer();
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


}
```

**ChatClient.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author nick
 */
public class ChatClient extends JFrame implements Runnable, ActionListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    String TAG = "kushal ";
    IChat ic;
    int oldx, oldy;
    JTextField jtf;
    JTextArea jta;

    public ChatClient() {
        try {
            Remote remote = Naming.lookup("//localhost:1099/chat");
            ic = (IChat) remote;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }



        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);

        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                ArrayList<Point> list = ic.get();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChatClient();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      /*  try {
            ic.put(TAG + jtf.getText());
            jtf.setText("");
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }*/

    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        oldx = e.getX();
        oldy = e.getY();


    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        Graphics g = getGraphics();

        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        g.drawLine(oldx, oldy, x, y);
        oldx = x;
        oldy = y;


    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

**IChat.java**

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author new
 */
public interface  IChat extends Remote{

    public void put(Point p) throws RemoteException;
    public ArrayList<Point> get() throws RemoteException;
}
```

**Error in ChatServer.java : ChatServer is not abstract and does not override abstract method get() in IChat**

**get() in ChatServer cannot implement get() in IChat
  return type ArrayList is not compatible with ArrayList
----**

Any help would be greatful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** You have **Not created** the `Implementation` **class** for the `Interface`.

**Eg:**

```
    IChatImpl implements IChat{

    public void put(Point p) throws RemoteException{



    }

    public ArrayList<Point> get() throws RemoteException{




    }
}
```

**////////////////////////////////Edited part/////////////////////////////**

**I think you have not overridden this method......**

`public ArrayList<String>`

**It should be....**

`public ArrayList<Point>`

Comment: but I am here implementing the IChat in the server. Can you please elaborate you answer please..

Comment: @nick, you need 4 classes........ `ChatInterface`, `ChatInterfaceImpl`, `ChatServer`, `ChatClient`.

Comment: I don't think so. ChatServer implementing IChat is perfectly valid. Even if you were right, that should never throw this exception. @KumarVivekMitra

Comment: In my answer I have already said what you say in your edit. @KumarVivekMitra

Comment: But I am getting connect exception at this line Naming.bind("//localhost:1099/chat", this);

Answer (score 0):

There are other problems here, but the cause of the connect exception is that you haven't started the RMI Registry on the server host.